# iOS: drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates: doesn't draw a AVPlayerLayer content

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, avplayer

I tried to take a snapshot of a `UIView` which contains an `AVPlayerLayer`, however the video part was drawn black. On the other hand, when I use `resizableSnapshotViewFromRect:afterScreenUpdates:withCapInsets:` then the resulting view contains the video snapshot correctly. However, I cannot get an image out of it, so I'm stuck with `UIView` instead of `UIImage`.

I thought that unlike `renderInContex`, `drawViewHierarchyInRect` should capture all the "special" OpenGL and video layers also. Is this not possible?